# PHP constant is sometimes not replaced by its defined value

Tags: php, codeigniter, constants

I'm quite confused by this problem I'm having as the code produces intermittent results.

I have a PHP application developed in CodeIgniter, a part of the software sends review emails with a link in. The link is declared like this in the code and this link is used to build the HTML email body:

```
$link = BASE_URL.'/review?id='.$review_id;
```

BASE_URL is a constant defined like so:

```
define('BASE_URL', 'http://www.domain-name.com');
```

Most of the time the link in the email is well formed and the constant is replaced with the domain name. However we've had replies to the review email where the user says the link does not work for them. Then looking at the link in the email to which they replied to, the link then has this url:

```
base_url/review?id=1234
```

Now this seems like very strange behaviour as the code produces 2 different results. What could be the cause of such an issue? Has any experienced something like this before?

Comment: `A constant is case-sensitive by default.` BASE_URL !== base_url

Comment: @MarkBaker, yes I am aware, the link in the email looks just like that. No where in the code is the constant defined in lower case. It's possible the link is actually uppercase but our mail client (Google mail) has lowercased the link, which could explain the lowercase-ness.

Comment: why do to define base_url as constant when codeigniter provides you with the function: "base_url()" which return the value you need?

Comment: but looks like used in lower case, turn on all errors displaying you should see notice like this: `Notice: Use of undefined constant base_url - assumed 'base_url' in ... on line ...`

Comment: I have done a grep -RH "base_url" * through the entire code base and there is not base_url string defined.

Comment: @DmitryK, it is to help with different development environments.

Comment: try to name it something else, maybe codeigniter uses the same name for constant....just guessing (even thought it is not in the list: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/general/reserved_names.html)

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you first use the framework itself for base_url();

other than that, if you can't track it down, I suggest logging the link you send to a file and see what value it gets when that link it sent.

Where is the definition taking place? this indeed sounds like what lupatus wrote, so maybe you call it before you define it.

We're pretty much guessing as this is 101 debugging :)

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php echo base_url();?>
```

Replace Above code with BASE_URL

Comment: This guy can end world hunger.

Comment: Martin don't be panic. i know you are genius sala.